# GET JSON VALUE IN C# OUT OF CONFIG

Tags: c#, json

im trying to get a value of JSON with the substring from a config,

```
 using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
            {
                string json = wc.DownloadString("****");

                
                dynamic dobj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
              
                string kek = dobj[0].ServerSystem.isActive;
              
                if(kek == "True")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(kek);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(kek);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
               
                

            }
```

JSON:

```
[
    {
        "ServerSystem": {
            "isActive": "True",
            "Time": "120S"
        }
        
       
    },
    {
        "License1": {
            "Description": "Lorem ipsum dolor gg amet",
            "Value": "1"
        }
        
       
    }
]
```

But i want to get the Value ServerSystem.[FROMCONFIG], but i dont know how to insert it, so i know how to read from a config, but i cant just dO: string kek = dobj[0].ServerSystem + ".BLALBALA";

So how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Actually your pseudocode nearly got it right.

```
var keytoget = "Time"; 
string value dobj[0].ServerSystem[keytoget]
```

Comment: Danke / Thanks!!

Comment: @Sebastian  You're welcome. If the answer helped you, please upvote and/or accept ...